# Display progressbar in webview while loading webpage

Tags: android, android-webview

I have made a WebView activity for my website and want to add a loading round icon like [loading image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVW9y.gif) to show the progress of webpage download.
How do i add such a ProgressBar to my activity ?

MainActivity.java

```
package club.moviestreet.www.webviewapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings= mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebView.loadUrl("http://webatozs.com/p/");
        // Line of Code for opening links in app
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (!url.startsWith("http://lightlobbies.com/p/")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    //Code For Back Button
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mywebView.canGoBack())
        {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }

        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following class

```
 public class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient {
 @Override
 public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
 super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
 }

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
 }
  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { 
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    // set your image from drawable folder 
    pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
 }  
}
```

And call in `onCreate()` method

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

   webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override on more method `onPageFinished`

```
    package club.moviestreet.www.webviewapp;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.webkit.WebSettings;
        import android.webkit.WebView;
        import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;
    ProgressBar pbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        pbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        WebSettings webSettings= mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebView.loadUrl("http://webatozs.com/p/");
        // Line of Code for opening links in app
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (!url.startsWith("http://lightlobbies.com/p/")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

paste below xml in your `activity_main.xml`..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"/>
        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/webview"></WebView> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://gyazo.com/8fc4e12e10643d8438daec64c044de60   see this error sir

Comment: i paste in that in activity_main.xml            <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

Comment: @subhasishbose remove all the xml code from your `activity_main.xml`  and paste only above `xml` which i given to you

Comment: after using the code first page show only half screen in my tab and rest pages not opening, and also the loading icon come only in first screen but at the top i want it in center

Answer (score 0):

The below code will set a callback when the page has loaded successfully.

```
mywebView .setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //Page loading has finished. Hide the progressbar here.
    }


});     
mywebView.loadUrl("http://lightlobbies.com/p/");
```